# How to print row of dataframe that purrr::map is acting on in R

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse, purrr

I am using `purrr::map` to run a time-consuming function on a long data frame list-column and I want to print an indicator of the row that's being acted up so that I can keep track of progress.

Here's a small example:

When I run this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(carb) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(n = map(data, nrow))
```

I would like to output the `carb` of the row that's being acted upon:

```
#> 4
#> 1
#> 2
#> 3
#> 6
#> 8
```

Which you could get by using a `for` loop like so:

```
df <-
    mtcars %>% 
    group_by(carb) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(n = NA)
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    print(df$carb[i])
    df$n[i] <- list(nrow(df$data[[i]]))
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could run through `carb` at the same time you run through `data` using `map2()`.  Then you can add a `print()` statement to your function to output the `carb`.

```
dat = mtcars %>% 
    group_by(carb) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(n = map2(data, carb, ~{
        print(.y)
        nrow(.x)
        }) 
        )

[1] 4
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 6
[1] 8

dat
# A tibble: 6 x 3
   carb data               n        
  <dbl> <list>             <list>   
1     4 <tibble [10 x 11]> <int [1]>
2     1 <tibble [7 x 11]>  <int [1]>
3     2 <tibble [10 x 11]> <int [1]>
4     3 <tibble [3 x 11]>  <int [1]>
5     6 <tibble [1 x 11]>  <int [1]>
6     8 <tibble [1 x 11]>  <int [1]>
```

I used the formula syntax for convenience, where `.x` refers to the first vector in `map2()` and `.y` the second.  You can do an anonymous function, instead, if it's clearer. (I'm not sure I love the brackets with the tilde.)

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(carb) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(n = map2(data, carb, function(x, y) {
        print(y)
        nrow(x)
        })
        )
```